# Ubuntu 18.04 (MSI GS66 Stealth) primary display blank, external display functional

Tags: 18.04, display-resolution, screen, monitor, external-monitor

I've an MSI GS66 Stealth laptop which came with Windows installed, alongside which I installed Ubuntu 18.04 with NVIDIA proprietary drivers.

Connecting an external monitor to my laptop through HDMI is how I've been using my laptop these days as the laptop's screen doesn't show *anything*: the screen doesn't have any glow, it's just "off". In this post I refer to the laptop's screen as the *primary* display and an external monitor connected via HDMI as the *secondary* display.

**I'm looking for help in bringing the primary display back.**

##### How it came to this

I had a secondary display connected and was working away with both screens functional. Took a break and didn't press any keys or move the mouse for a few minutes and I saw the laptop screen go dim and then completely dark. This looked a little odd because if the laptop was going into sleep because of inactivity, the secondary display should follow suit. However, it's just my laptop screen that turned dark/off. Keyboard backlight kept glowing as normal.

Restarting the laptop made no difference. After that episode, I always need a secondary display else I'm sitting blind without knowing what is going on.

##### System details

###### `inxi -G`

```
Graphics:  Card-1: Intel CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
           Card-2: NVIDIA TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q Refresh]
           Display Server: x11 (X.Org 1.20.8 ) drivers: i915,nvidia
           Resolution: 1920x1080@60.00hz
           OpenGL: renderer: NVIDIA GeForce RTX 2070 with Max-Q Design/PCIe/SSE2
           version: 4.6.0 NVIDIA 520.61.05
```

###### `nvidia-smi`

*(first line)*
`NVIDIA-SMI 520.61.05    Driver Version: 520.61.05    CUDA Version: 11.8`

###### `xrandr`

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-0 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 598mm x 336mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  59.94    50.00  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1600x900      60.00  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1024x768      75.03    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-4 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
eDP-1-1 connected primary (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
   15360x8640    15.83    28.85  
   7680x4320     15.83    59.99    59.99    59.99  
   5120x2880     59.99    59.99  
   4096x2304     59.99    59.98  
   3840x2160     60.00    60.01    59.98    59.97  
   3200x1800     59.96    59.94  
   2880x1620     59.96    59.97  
   2560x1600     59.99    59.97  
   2560x1440     59.99    59.99    59.96    59.95  
   2048x1536     60.00  
   1920x1440     60.00  
   1856x1392     60.01  
   1792x1344     60.01  
   2048x1152     59.99    59.98    59.90    59.91  
   1920x1200     59.88    59.95  
   1920x1080     60.01    59.97    59.96    59.93  
   1600x1200     60.00  
   1680x1050     59.95    59.88  
   1600x1024     60.17  
   1400x1050     59.98  
   1600x900      59.99    59.94    59.95    59.82  
   1280x1024     60.02  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1400x900      59.96    59.88  
   1280x960      60.00  
   1440x810      60.00    59.97  
   1368x768      59.88    59.85  
   1360x768      59.80    59.96  
   1280x800      59.99    59.97    59.81    59.91  
   1152x864      60.00  
   1280x720      60.00    59.99    59.86    59.74  
   1024x768      60.04    60.00  
   960x720       60.00  
   928x696       60.05  
   896x672       60.01  
   1024x576      59.95    59.96    59.90    59.82  
   960x600       59.93    60.00  
   960x540       59.96    59.99    59.63    59.82  
   800x600       60.00    60.32    56.25  
   840x525       60.01    59.88  
   864x486       59.92    59.57  
   800x512       60.17  
   700x525       59.98  
   800x450       59.95    59.82  
   640x512       60.02  
   720x450       59.89  
   700x450       59.96    59.88  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x405       59.51    58.99  
   684x384       59.88    59.85  
   680x384       59.80    59.96  
   640x400       59.88    59.98  
   576x432       60.06  
   640x360       59.86    59.83    59.84    59.32  
   512x384       60.00  
   512x288       60.00    59.92  
   480x270       59.63    59.82  
   400x300       60.32    56.34  
   432x243       59.92    59.57  
   320x240       60.05  
   360x202       59.51    59.13  
   320x180       59.84    59.32  
  1680x1050 (0x1c5) 146.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1680 start 1784 end 1960 total 2240 skew    0 clock  65.29KHz
        v: height 1050 start 1053 end 1059 total 1089           clock  59.95Hz
  1280x1024 (0x1c8) 108.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1328 end 1440 total 1688 skew    0 clock  63.98KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1025 end 1028 total 1066           clock  60.02Hz
  1280x800 (0x1c9) 83.500MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  1280 start 1352 end 1480 total 1680 skew    0 clock  49.70KHz
        v: height  800 start  803 end  809 total  831           clock  59.81Hz
  1024x768 (0x1ce) 65.000MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width  1024 start 1048 end 1184 total 1344 skew    0 clock  48.36KHz
        v: height  768 start  771 end  777 total  806           clock  60.00Hz
  800x600 (0x1d0) 40.000MHz +HSync +VSync
        h: width   800 start  840 end  968 total 1056 skew    0 clock  37.88KHz
        v: height  600 start  601 end  605 total  628           clock  60.32Hz
  640x480 (0x1d4) 25.175MHz -HSync -VSync
        h: width   640 start  656 end  752 total  800 skew    0 clock  31.47KHz
        v: height  480 start  490 end  492 total  525           clock  59.94Hz
```

###### `sudo lshw -c video`

```
  *-display                 
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: TU106M [GeForce RTX 2070 Mobile / Max-Q Refresh]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:01:00.0
       version: a1
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nvidia latency=0
       resources: irq:186 memory:ac000000-acffffff memory:80000000-8fffffff memory:90000000-91ffffff ioport:3000(size=128) memory:ad000000-ad07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: CometLake-H GT2 [UHD Graphics]
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 05
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:183 memory:ab000000-abffffff memory:40000000-4fffffff ioport:4000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

##### "Display settings" screenshots

**`Single Display` is enabled by default.** I've a BenQ monitor connected at the moment, at work I've an HP monitor.
[image: Single Display]

**On going to `Join Displays`**, primary display has an unusually high resolution `15360 x 8640` (I don't remember ever setting that high a resolution) and an even weirder refresh rate of `15.83 Hz` (what?!).

[image: Joint Displays]

**On "correcting" the resolution of primary display** to `1920 x 1080` (refresh rate automatically switches to a much saner `120 Hz`) and hitting *Apply*, primary display still remains blank. And **Display settings go back to Single Display** (first screenshot).

[image: Hit Apply]

---

I know the primary display exists because I can move the mouse pointer "out" of the secondary display.

When booting my laptop, the Ubuntu login screen shows up on my secondary display — GRUB menu never shows up, likely because HDMI drivers are not loaded up before an operating system is selected? — after I assume the GRUB menu has timed out.

Is there anything I can do in software? Or is something wrong with the hardware? The video [Laptop Screen is Black (But Still Powered On and Running!)](https://youtu.be/4VOOWDRryzE) looked useful but I don't want to go about opening up my work laptop without knowing what I'm getting into.

Comment: You stated in your post that the PC has windows installed. Does the primary display work on windows?  Is it possible the primary display hardware broke/died?

Comment: The screen where I can select an OS doesn't show up and since Ubuntu is at the top of the menu, that's the OS that gets loaded. So I've not been able to verify if primary display works on Windows. Hardware being broken does seem like a possibility at this point.

Comment: For these cases what I recommend is to go back to nouveau driver and then install the drivers from NVIDIA's website. However be careful, there's a slight chance your system may not boot to graphics if you do that; make sure you know how to uninstall from cmd line to revert what you did if that happens.

Answer (score 1):

I would first make sure that this is not a hardware issue. It is a relitively simple test. Turn the system off, disconnect ALL external devices (you can keep AC adapter connected), turn on the system.
Does the internal display turn on during post when nothing else is connected to the laptop?
If so does it work in another OS (use a bootable USB with the Ubuntu desktop installer or Linux Mint, or anything else to test).